# Using mapreduce with Mongoose, not able to find emit function

Tags: mongoose, mapreduce, typescript-typings

I am trying to create a mapreduce function using the example on the Mongoose website located [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html).  This application is being created using TypeScript and node.js.

This example uses a function called emit which I am not able to find.  I keep getting an error indicating the function cannot be found.  I added the references to the types at the top of the file for Mongoose and Mongodb but this did not work either:

```
///<reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts" />
///<reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts" />
```

I would just like to know where my issue could be.  The examples I drew upon did not have to add these typings.  Granted, I am using TypeScript for my case and the examples do not use TypeScript, but I would think this would still work.